# How can I round up to the next multiple of 0.05 using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

How can I round a floating-point number to the hundredth place, while also rounding up to the nearest multiple of 0.05 in SQL Server.

Example `4.93` would round to `4.95`

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173313/why-is-rounding-in-sql-closed-as-off-topic).

Answer (score 9):

Multiply it by 20, then round it to next integer, then divide by 20.

Comment: +1, though for some reason like [this post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/08/09/how-to-round-to-the-nearest-whole-multiple-or-fraction-in-sql/) I prefer the last operation to be a multiply rather than a divide (eg divide by 5, round to 2dp then multiply by 5)

Comment: You say round to the _next_ integer. Shouldn't that be to the _closest_ integer? For example, 1.01 should be rounded to 1.00 (from 20.20, 20 -- _not_ 20.20, 21), _not_ to 1.05.

Comment: @Camil - OP wants to round it up. There were a clarifying comment on that from him, but it seems to be gone now.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this formula, where `@round_to` is the number to a multiple of which you'd like to round.  `@round_updown` chooses up or down rounding: set it to `0` to round down, to `@round_to - 0.000001` to round up, or to `@round_to / 2` to use middle rounding.

```
select  @round_to*cast((@value+@round_updown)/@round_to as int)
```

For example:

```
select  0.05*cast((4.93+0.025)/0.05 as int)
```